# How can I modify this to get a random record on the many end of a join?

Tags: sql, t-sql, random

Here is my query:

```
    Select Top 10 CS.CaseStudyID,
    CS.Title,
    CSI.ImageFileName
From CaseStudy CS
Left Join CaseStudyImage CSI On CS.CaseStudyID = CSI.CaseStudyID
And CSI.CSImageID in(
    Select Min(CSImageID) -- >not really satisfactory
    From CaseStudyImage
    Group By CaseStudyID
    )
Order By CS.CaseStudyID ASC
```

Instead of min(CSImageID) I'd like a random record from my CaseStudyImage table that corresponds to the particular case study

Can anyone point me in the right direction pleas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ranking function and newid() to create randomize order with grouping.

```
WITH CSI AS (
    SELECT CSI.CaseStudyID, CSI.ImageFileName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CSI.CaseStudyID ORDER BY newid()) AS RowNumber
    FROM CaseStudyImage CSI
)
SELECT TOP (10) CS.CaseStudyID, CS.Title, CSI.ImageFileName
FROM CaseStudy CS LEFT JOIN CSI On CS.CaseStudyID = CSI.CaseStudyID
WHERE CSI.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY CS.CaseStudyID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

usually, just `ORDER BY NEWID()` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`?

Comment: No Limit in T-SQL or rand (there's newid()) and I'm geting lost combining the equivalent Top with order by newid()

Comment: Sorry there is Rand but its not helping me yet

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175776(SQL.80).aspx) describes 3 techniques for random sampling in t-sql. It depends on how much control you have over your table structure one of them might do want you want.